# Forwarding FQDN http requests to different servers

Tags: redirect, iptables, squid, forward, fqdn

I have two http servers (Apache Tomcat [192.168.1.5:8080] and Jetty [192.168.1.55:9090]) behind the router (Linux [192.168.1.200], iptables). I also have a public domain: domain.net.

My question:
How to redirect

`sub1.domain.net to server1 (192.168.1.5:8080/app1)`

and

`sub2.domain.net to server2 (192.168.1.55:9090/app2)`

?

I tried to redirect using iptables, but it can forward only ip addresses (even I write FQDN it first translate it into IP address and then transfer). I also heard about squid, but maybe I do sth wrong with redirection because squid can redirect request using FQDN but address in browser is changed - I need this address not to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single "frontal server" with Apache,
which would be proxifying to different servers on your LAN based on the FQDN,
but that's  just a suggestion :)